# apa6 package "man" document mode produces unwanted page 3

Tags: apa6

I'm trying to write my thesis as closely conforming to APA6 style as reasonable. I've scraped together a preamble from answers on this page that is messy, but works pretty well.

The only problem is that this code produces an unwated page 3 between the abstract page 2 and the table of contents page 4 (against APA guidelines). This page 3 only has the title of the thesis on it and I can't seem to get rid of it. It also appears in the table of contents.

This page disappears if I switch document mode to `doc`, so `man` mode seems to be the problem. However `man` mode most closely resembles what the APA6 guidelines dictate (running head and page number on page 1, abstract on page 2, amongst other things), so I don't want to switch to `doc`.

So how to I get rid of this pesky page 3 in `man` mode?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,man,notimes,draftfirst,noextraspace]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{nextpage}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}   % A4-paper format
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}  % A4-paper format
\setlength{\topmargin}{-\headheight-\headsep}        % A4-paper format
\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}       % A4-paper format
\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}       % A4-paper format
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.92cm}        % A4-paper format
\setlength{\textheight}{24.62cm}       % A4-paper format
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}  % Set running head to textwidth

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000
\hyphenpenalty = 10000
\exhyphenpenalty = 10000


\raggedright
\setlength\parindent{.5in}
\bibindent=.5in
\setlength{\itemindent}{.5in}
\parskip 0pt



\captionsetup{justification=justified,font=singlespacing}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},            
}

\linespread{2}



\title{The effects of intervention on dependent variable}
\shorttitle{Effect of intervention}
\author{Yours Truly}
\affiliation{LaTeX University}
\date{}

\abstract{placeholder abstract}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
Theory 

\clearpage

\section{Method}
Method

\clearpage

\section{Results}
Results

\clearpage

\section{Discussion}
Discussion text

\clearpage
\section{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My doubt is: why using the `man` option that produces the worst typesetting on the face of earth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `donotrepeattitle` to the `\documentclass` options:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  man,
  notimes,
  draftfirst,
  noextraspace,
  donotrepeattitle
]{apa6}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it. I wonder why this is not in the official documentation.